# how do i make a kml file as a fiona supported drivers while using jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, geopandas, fiona

```
data = geopandas.read_file(path_filename,driver='kml')
```

data and I'm getting the error:

> unsupported driver: 'KML'

Comment: Code is not sufficient, please also share the kml file if possible.

Comment: this is an `ogr/gdal` issue

Answer (score 1):

```
gd.io.file.fiona.drvsupport.supported_drivers['kml'] = 'rw'
gd.io.file.fiona.drvsupport.supported_drivers['KML'] = 'rw'
gd.io.file.fiona.drvsupport.supported_drivers['LIBKML'] = 'rw'
fiona.drvsupport.supported_drivers['kml'] = 'rw'  # enable KML support which is disabled by default
fiona.drvsupport.supported_drivers['KML'] = 'rw'  # enable KML support which is disabled by default
fiona.drvsupport.supported_drivers['LIBKML'] = 'rw'  # enable KML support which is disabled by default
```

Sometimes adding kml to the list of supported drivers works.

Comment: This works for me as a quick fix. Essentially, the driver is missing from the fiona package. You can check by doing: "import fiona" then "fiona.supported_drivers" to check. The code above just add the KML to the list with read and write ability.

Comment: Same problem, this did not solved it in my case.